# How to display <div> inline surrounded with text?

Tags: css, html, inline

I would like to display a `<div>` element inline so that it is surrounded with text.

My code is:

```
<span>Here is some <div class="a"></div> text</span>
```

Let's say, the class `"a"` is defined as below:

```
.a {
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background-color:#f00;
}
```

The result should be like this:

[image]

Is it doable? Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's a CSS property `display: inline-block;` but I don't know how compatible with browsers it is (works fine in my FF)

<strike>I'll do some quick testing for you.</strike>

**Update**

I've tested it in Chrome, FF and IE.
Works in IE8, not IE7. Chrome is fine as is FF

Comment: inline-block doesn't work (or doesn't work correct) in IE6/7, but theres a hack for that if you have to support them: http://homepage.ntlworld.com/spartanicus/ie_block_level_element_inline-block_hack.htm

Answer (score 3):

Basically just add `display: inline-block;`
You might want to tune it a bit afterward, but this should work everywhere except IE6

Comment: Works in safari, chrome, opera, FF, IE8, won't work in IE6/IE7 though