# CSS hide the content of a div overlapped by a div with absolute position

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, popup

I have a div which hide/display on hover. The position set is absolute so background of div becomes transparent. If position set to relative then the parent div height is affected on hover.

So how can the background made block so that the content is not visible.

**Sample given:**

```js
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $("#hover").hover(function() {
            $("#message").toggle();
        });
    });
```

```css
#message {
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px #888888;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#"id="hover" >Click Here</a>
<div id="message">
  <b>Hidden Content</b>
  <br/>This is a very large content which overlaps the content at background.<br/><br/>So the content in background should not be seen.
</div>
<div>This is another text whose content should be hidden under the popup.</div><br/>
<div>One more text added whose content is visible even if the hidden content is visible.</div>
```

Comment: Your code does not work.

Comment: @AamirKhan Modified the code... Now I want to show the message as popup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display <div> inline surrounded with text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256272/how-to-display-div-inline-surrounded-with-text)

Comment: @Quentin to question is shortened. Please remove from hold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without jQuery.

```css
#hover {
 position: relative;
}

#hover:hover > #message {
 opacity: 1;
 margin-left: calc(100% + 20px);
}

#message {
 width: 100px;
 margin-left: 50%;
 padding: 10px;
 background: #8E8EF2;
 position: absolute;
 transition: .5s all ease;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 color: #fff;
 opacity: 0;
 left: 0;
 top: 50%;
}

#message:before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 border: 10px solid transparent;
 border-right: 10px solid #8E8EF2;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 left: -20px;
 top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="hover">
 Hover me, please
 <div id="message">
  <b><u>I am here</u></b>
 </div>
</a>
```

Comment: I used class instead of id. And it does not display any content.

Comment: .popopMessage {
    position: relative;
}

    .popopMessage:hover > .popover-right {
        opacity:1;
        margin-left: calc(100% + 20px);
    }

.popover-right {
    display: none;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #E2E7EF;
    position: absolute;
    transition: .5s all ease;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    color: #333;
    opacity: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
}

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $("#hover").hover(function() {
            $("#message").toggle();
        });
    });
```

```css
    #message {
        display: none;
        max-width: 300px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 18px 0;
        padding: 18px 20px;
        background-color: #eef4f9;
        /* easy rounded corners for modern browsers */
        -moz-border-radius: 6px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
        border-radius: 6px;
    }
     #message::after {
        content: " ";
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        top: -10px;
        left: 20px;
        margin: 0;
        border-top: 0;
        border-left: 10px solid transparent;
        border-right: 10px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 10px solid #eef4f9;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="hover">Hover me</a>

<div id="message">
  <b><u>I am here</u></b>
</div>
```